# foreach for nested array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like so:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => test
    [2] => 2014-05-06
    [3] => Blah, Blah, Blah
    [4] => admin-uploads/test.jpg
  )
  [1] => Array(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => Test 3
    [2] => 2014-05-07
    [3] => This is the second Test.vcxvjmckxlmvcx
    [4] => admin-uploads/
  )
  [2] => Array(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => Test 3
    [2] => 2014-05-07
    [3] => This is the second Test.
    [4] => admin-uploads/test2.jpg
  )
)
```

and I am trying to write a `foreach` to have each of those array in the table row and the values in table data

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
  echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What output are you looking for?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: What you've got is a 2-dimensional array (matrix). You can refer to `$data[row 0..2][col 0..4]`, or use _foreach_ to give you an array for each row. Your `$value` should end up with only 3 array pointers, not 3x5=15 printable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach would be using a foreach loop with the key/value clause:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
   echo '<tr>';
   foreach($value as $sub_value) {
      echo '<td>' . $sub_value . '</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, use implode:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $value).'</td></tr>' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
echo "abc";
$data = array(  
                0 => array(0 => 1, 1 => "test", 2 => "2014-05-06", 3 => "Blah Blah Blah", 4 => "admin-uploads/test.jpg"), 
                1 => array(0 => 9, 1 => "Text 3", 2 => "2014-05-07", 3=>"This is the second test.vcxvjmckxlmvcx", 4 => "admin-uploads/"), 
                2 => array(0 => 10, 1 => "Text 3", 2 => "2014-05-07", 3=>"This is the second test.", 4 => "admin-uploads/test2.jpg")
            );

foreach($data as $item)
{
    foreach($item as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "Key: ".$key." <br> Value:".$value."<br><br>";
    }   
}
?>
```

should work for your "weired" array (which is just nested by the way)